# Transform from preg_replace to preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, php-7

Sorry for repeating the question, but I have individual case with using preg_replace function. This is the function to replace variables ($vars) in template ($data) from their names to their values

```
function replace_vars($data, array $vars) {
    return preg_replace(array('/\{\{([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\}\}/e', '/\{\{([a-zA-Z0-9_]+):(\d+)\}\}/e'),
        array("\$vars['\\1']", "\$vars['\\1'][\\2]"), $data);
}
```

$template fragment

```
<td>{{name}}</td>
<td>{{active_items}}</td>
<td>{{percents}} %</td>
```

function call

```
$report = '';
$f['name'] = 'some name';
$f['active_items'] = 237;
$f['percents'] = 'some name';
$report .= $mailer->replace_vars($template, $f);
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, it's simple.

```php
preg_replace_callback([...], function($matches) use ($vars) {
  # Use ($vars) will inherit it from the current scope
  $v = $vars[$matches[1]]; # Select item with key of capturing group 1
  if ($matches[2]) { # If group 2 was matched
    $v = $v[$matches[2]]; # Select contents of item with the same key as it's value from the previous item
  }
  return $v; # Replace it.
}, [...]);
```

It will replace every match with `$var[\1]` or `$var[\1][\2]` if group 2 was matched.